# Nilpotents of $\Bbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to find the nilpotents of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_n$.

Let $\bar{a}$ $\in$ $\Bbb{Z}_n$ be a nilpotent.

Then by definition, $\exists$ $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\bar{a}^m$ = $\bar{0}$.

From here, we get that $a^m$ $\in$ $n\Bbb{Z}$.

So we have that $n|a^m$.

Let $p$ be any prime divisor of $n$.

Clearly $p|n$.

Now $p|n$ and $n|a^m$.

So we have that $p|a^m$.

So from here, $p|a$.

Let $n = p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}..p_k^{r_k}$ i.e. the prime factorization of $n$.

By the above observation, $p_i|a$ for all $i = 1,2,...k$.

Let $r$ = $max$$({r_1,r_2..r_k})$ .

Then first of all, I want to know that how can we claim that $a^r =0$?

And from here, how could I find the nilpotents of the ring?

Comment: You just try to show that (i) any nilpotent element is divisible by $p_1 p_2 \dots p_k$; (ii) any element divisible by that thing is nilpotent. I believe you have almost finished part (i), and part (ii) is also not far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_i|a\Rightarrow p_i^r|a^r\Rightarrow p_1^r\cdots p_k^r|a^r$, then we get $n|p_1^r\cdots p_k^r|a^r$ (because $r_i\le r$). Thus $\tilde{a}^r=0$

And the last bit of your argument shows that, if $n|a^r$ then $a$ is nilpotent. So you have the following: $\tilde{a}$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $n|a^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$